# SoundCloud API from Local Host

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to run SoundCloud API and testing it on my local machine. For HTML I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" ng-app >
<head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id = "results">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And for my script file :

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'my_API_key'
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  SC.get('/tracks', { genres: 'rap'}, function(tracks) {
   $(tracks).each(function(index, track) {
      $('#results').append($('<li></li>').html(track.title + ' - ' + track.genre));
    });
  });
});
```

But when I run, I get the following in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=rap&client_id=my_APIKey&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https,
>   chrome-extension-resource.window.SC.SC.Helper.merge._xhrRequest @
>   sdk.js:1window.SC.SC.Helper.merge._request @
>   sdk.js:1window.SC.SC.Helper.merge._apiRequest @
>   sdk.js:1window.SC.SC.Helper.merge.get @ sdk.js:1(anonymous function) @
>   script.js:5n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @
>   jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
>       sdk.js:1 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=rap&client_id=my_API_key&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200'.

Comment: wrong sdk version, no https, do you use a webserver to run your files? https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

Comment: I'm using http-server and its works now, thanks

Comment: nice to read that, you may can delete your question.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got this to work? I'm stuck at the same issue.

Comment: @Thomas you need to run a server. check out : https://github.com/indexzero/http-server  . Follow the install instructions, run the server from the right directory inside terminal or your console (http-server) then access the file via http://localhost:8080 . It's been a while, but I believe that's how it should work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. When I get it to work, I'll answer the question here.